# LibGDX's HTML project doesn't show anything in Browser

Tags: eclipse, libgdx

The question is self explanatory, when I run my demo-html project as a Web Application and I open Chrome with the provided link by eclipse, my browser doesn't show the image it is supposed to show in a new project.. However, the tab displays the correct title "Demo". Can somebody help me with this?

Eclipse after Running the project:

[image]

And Chrome running the app:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't run it as web application. The simplest way is to run

```
gradle html:superDev
```

in command line. I'm not very familiar with Eclipse, so here a guide how to run it via IDE from the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Eclipse#running-your-project):

> Right click the html project, Run As -> External Tools Configuration. Create a new configuration by double clicking the Program entry in the left sidebar. Give the configuration a name, e.g. GWT SuperDev. Set the location field to the gradlew.bat (Windows) or gradlew (Linux, Mac) file. Set the working directory to the root folder of your project. Specify html:superDev as the Argument. Press 'Apply', then 'Run'. Wait until you see the message The code server is ready. in the console view, then open the URL http://localhost:8080/html. You can leave the server running. If you change code or assets, simply click the SuperDev Refresh button in the browser. This will recompile your app and reload the site.

In IntelliJ you can trivially run the gradle task itself.

Comment: My project was build based on the old libgdx-generator, not the new one for gradle users... so this is not going to work

Comment: There doesnt seem to be an archive of the old wiki, new one contains only gradle stuff. Creating gradle project and copying over old code should be easy enough. You can also check the libgdx forum.

Comment: Just doing it because I'm following a book (2015) that does the same way.  They say that for simpler projects there's no need to use the gradle set up, although they teach how to use it too. Anyway, thanks for your answer :)